# Merge Sort with no output what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++

I am struggling to understand why I am getting no output?

I am trying to learn how to implement a merge-sort algorithm. The way I went about this is first concatenating the two vectors and then implementing a function to sort the concatenated vector.

I am new to C++ programming.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void merge(vector<int> &array1, vector<int> &array2){
    
    vector<int> mergeArray;
    
    mergeArray.insert(mergeArray.end(), array1.begin(), array1.end());
    mergeArray.insert(mergeArray.end(), array2.begin(), array2.end());
    
}

void sort(vector<int> &mergeArray, vector<int> &sortedArray, int n, int i){
    
    if(n==0){
        return; 
    }
    if(mergeArray[i]>mergeArray[i+1]){
        sort(mergeArray,sortedArray,n-1,i+1);
        sortedArray.push_back(mergeArray[i+1]);
    }
    else{
        sort(mergeArray,sortedArray,n-1,i+1);
        sortedArray.push_back(mergeArray[i]); 
    }
    for(int x=0; x<sortedArray.size(); x++){
        cout << sortedArray[x];
    } 
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> array1 = {5,4,2}; 
    vector<int> array2 = {3,7,1};
    vector<int> mergeArray;
    vector<int> sortedArray;
    
    merge(array1,array2);
    sort(mergeArray,sortedArray,mergeArray.size() + sortedArray.size(),0);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void merge` inserts data into `mergeArray` and immediately discards this vector. It's essentially a no-op

Comment: You'll get answers, and they might well help you understand this case, but you haven't really shown _what you tried_ to solve your problem. That is, you've shown your program, but _most_ people don't just write a program in one shot. Did you try anything to see what `mergeArray.size()` was giving? Did you try printing out results part-way through to see what's happening? You should include _what you tried_ in your question and it is through that process that you learn to narrow down a broad problem into a specific one.

Comment: Please recheck merge sort algorithm. Your code does not seem to perform merge sort.

Answer (score 2):

The `mergeArray` vector in `merge` is local to the function, and `main` has no way of seeing the changes to `mergeArray`.

You could pass the array in as a reference parameter, *instead* of declaring it as a local variable:

```
void merge(vector<int> &mergeArray, vector<int> &array1, vector<int> &array2) {
  // ...
}
```

and call `merge` like this:

```
merge(mergeArray, array1,array2);
```

Notice that you are already doing this in your `sort` function. You need to do a similar thing for `merge`.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GVkqjS).